# ClassCastException - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, classcastexception, android-toolbar

after updated support libraries for material design I get a crash on some devices ( Samsung , Wiko )

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
com.wax.app.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:310)
android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2612)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:152)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:75)
android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:44)
android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:76)
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:164)
android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:738)
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I just added this to Progruard

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.v7.** {*;}
```

What can I do? Thanks :)

Edit: here onOptionsItemSelected() method, line 310 is between "int id" and first if statement

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.close) {
        NewsContainer fr = (NewsContainer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        fr.closePage();
        item.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (id == R.id.expand) {

        VisualizzabiliInApp fr1 = (VisualizzabiliInApp) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        fr1.expand();

        if (item.getTitle().equals("Mostra Filtri")) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_white_24dp);
            item.setTitle("Nascondi Filtri");
        } else {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_white_24dp);
            item.setTitle("Mostra Filtri");
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: @Ajeet you meant "piece" right? ;)

Comment: Well, the stacktrace is pretty unambiguous, MainActivity line 310. Post at least that, ideally the whole onOptionsItemSelected().

Comment: If your stacktrace points to a blank line in your source code, then you're not running the latest version of your code. Clean your project and try again. Otherwise, my guess is that either of the fragments returned from `findFragmentById` is not the fragment you're casting it to.